# VB.NET- Is there any way to bind two datatable in a datagrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I need help in binding values that are in two different datatable.

Example: I have a datable `x` and `y`. `x` has 4 column and some amount of rows and `y` has 1 column and the same amount of rows as x. Now i want this 1 column in datatable `y` to appear at the second position with the `x` in a datatable, like `x-y-x-x-x...`. This must be the order to display the column in the datagrid, but how to bind them?

Even if i bind them i need to format the column positions. Is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to load these from a database using a SQL Query ?

Comment: yes.... the two datatables contain values loaded from sql database.

Comment: so its better to this by a specific SQL command (query)

Answer (score 0):

a few options:

option 1: load the data into one table instead of two

option 2: merge the two datatables into one table, if they are all read-only

option 3: use unbound columns - bind one table but unbound another table

option 4: write a wrapper class to wrap the data and then bind the list (of the wrapper object) to the grid, something like:

```
Public Class MyData
    Private _rowA As tblARow
    Private _rowB As tblBrow
    Sub New(rowFromA As tblARow, rowFromB As tblBRow)
        _rowA = rowFromA
        _rowB = rowFromB
    End Sub

    Property ColumnA As String
        Get
            Return _rowA.ColumnA
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _rowA.ColumnA = value
        End Set
    End Property

    ' // Other properties...
End Class
```

Comment: i tried merging the datatables but how to edit the position of the columns in that datatable... i need columns like x-y-x-x-x

Comment: you could simply create a new table and copy the columns in the order you want

Comment: Thats the problem i cant do it... Its restricted... Is there any alternate??

Comment: how about option 4 - use wrapper class instead,  this is the ultimate solution and can suite almost all scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Create a dataset. In the dataset add a new table. That table should be created using your custom query. Within that table you should load the data and then retrieve it into your datagrid (you can also preview the data). It's easy. Use the visual tools from Visual Studio.